# Angular JS ng-message inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some input fields inside custom directive. I'm trying to use ng-message to display validation error text for the fields inside custom directive.

When I do submit, validation messages inside custom directive is not shown.

My question is, can I use ng-message inside directive, and trigger it using parent action from form controller, and the message is shown?

My app.js source sample

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMessages']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.identity = {};

   vm.save = function() {
      console.log('form data will submited to server');
   }
});
app.directive('nameInfo', function() {
   return {
     templateUrl: 'name.html',
     scope: {
       name: '=',
       submitted: '='
     }
   };
});
```

My html code

```
<form name="plnkrForm" novalidate ng-submit="plnkrForm.$valid && vm.save()">
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" data-ng-click="submitted=true">
       Update
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressOne" name="addressOne"
       placeholder="Address line 1" required="required" ng-model="vm.identity.addressOne" />
      <div role="alert" ng-messages="plnkrForm.addressOne.$error"
       data-ng-if="submitted && plnkrForm.addressOne.$invalid">
          <span class="error" ng-message="required">Required</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <name-info name="vm.identity.name" submitted="submitted"></name>
</form>
```

My directive template

```
<div class=form-group>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname" id="firstname"
    name="firstname" ng-model="name.firstname" required="required" />
   <div role="alert" ng-messages="plnkrForm.firstname.$error"
    data-ng-if="submitted && plnkrForm.firstname.$invalid">
      <span class="error" ng-message="required">Required</span>
   </div>
</div>

<div class=form-group>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middlename" id="middlename"
    name="middlename" ng-model="name.middlename" required="required" />
   <div role="alert" ng-messages="plnkrForm.middlename.$error"
    data-ng-if="submitted && plnkrForm.middlename.$invalid">
      <span class="error" ng-message="required">Required</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=form-group>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Lastname" id="lastname"
    name="lastname" ng-model="name.lastname" required="required" />
   <div role="alert" ng-messages="plnkrForm.lastname.$error"
    data-ng-if="submitted && plnkrForm.lastname.$invalid">
      <span class="error" ng-message="required">Required</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6c5cMTtxoxNHhpjm1DCo) for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have explicitly defined isolated scope for your directive, so `plnkrForm` does not exist. Quickest way to fix this is that you drop the isolated scope. Based on your example, you don't need it anyway.

So directive becomes

```
app.directive('nameInfo', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'name.html'
  };
});
```

And this being the case, directive is a bit of an overkill. You could get same result using `ng-include`, too. So you could replace this

```
<name-info 
  name="vm.identity.name" 
  submitted="submitted">
</name-info>
```

with this

```
<div ng-include="'name.html'"></div>
```

---

If you insist doing this using a directive and isolated scope, here's how it's done. Pass form into directive and use it in your template/link/controller and change template accordingly.

In your "main" page

```
<name-info form="plnkrForm" name="name"></name-info>
```

JavaScript

```
app.directive('nameInfo', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'name.html',
    scope: {
      form: '=',
      name: '='
    }
  };
});
```

Directive template

```
<div class=form-group>
  <input type="text" 
         class="form-control" 
         placeholder="Firstname" 
         name="firstname" 
         ng-model="name.firstname" 
         required="true">
  <div role="alert" 
       ng-messages="form.firstname.$error" 
       data-ng-if="form.$submitted && form.firstname.$invalid">
       <span class="error" ng-message="required">Required</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> Now, I know your intentions are good as you want to avoid "DRY". If
>   you study the examples, you'll notice that you get same result,
>   functionality and reusability by using simple `ng-include`. Here we
>   have achieved nothing but added, unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but how if I need isolated scope, and have separate controller in my directive?
Any way thanks for your reply.

Comment: Well... what would be the use case that needs isolated scope, or separate controller when it's about form fields?

Comment: In my case, I have form contain a lot of information, one of the information is Address entity (address line 1, house no, etc), this address will support google place and google map. So I don't want to make the controller of the page is too huge. Also there is manipulation of data, my resolution is to create directive with isolated scope, also because this directive will re-used in another page. I'm just trying to not doing repetition code, also trying to implement single principal.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: ng-include will only work inside forms named "plnkrForm", so not very reusable, right? I think this is a good argument for using your directive example here instead?

Comment: Well, it depends. You got point there but then again one could add the form inside current template and in how many use cases (across the site) you'd be asking for the user's information. So, it depends :)

Comment: upvoted for `Here we have achieved nothing but added, unnecessary complexity.`