# Angular ng-messages inside custom directive inside ng-repeat wrong behaviour

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-messages

I have same problem as described in this toppic:
[Angular JS ng-message inside directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869023/angular-js-ng-message-inside-directive)

Unfortunatelly that solutions is not working for me, because I am using my custom directive inside ng-repeat. So now ng-messages work only when error condition is fulfilled for all inputs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/lJT48bmYvR9DGFliIYDH?p=preview

I have tried many ways for creating ng-messages condition but nothing worked properly. Two of them You can find in above plunker:

```
ng-messages="form.doubleInputLeft.$error"
ng-messages="form['doubleInputRight' + $index].$error"
```

Please help me,
Regards

Comment: Please don't prefix the name of the directive with `ng-`. That prefix is reserved for core directives. For more info,  see [AngularJS Wiki -- Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `input` elements to work inside an `ng-repeat`, the index must be included as part of the name attribute.

```
    <!-- index must be included in the name attribute --
    <input name="doubleInputLeft" class="form-control ngMessageSample" type="{{inputType}}"  ng-model="modelLeft" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    -->
    <input name="doubleInputLeft{{index}}" class="form-control ngMessageSample" type="{{inputType}}"  ng-model="modelLeft" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20" required>
    <div ng-messages="form['doubleInputLeft'+index].$error" class="ngMessagesClass" ng-messages-multiple>
      <div ng-message="minlength" class="ngMessageClass"> {{leftInputHeading}} must have at least 2 characters.</div>
      <div ng-message="maxlength" class="ngMessageClass"> {{leftInputHeading}} must have at most 20 characters.</div>
    </div>
```

Otherwise, the repeated elements will have duplicate names.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHTywuyFfArWDpWwe5Ia?p=preview)

Comment: Thank You so much @georgeawg. That was the last thing i would think about. I will also change directive names. Regads and thanks again !