# validation of input field in directive that is included in form controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am new to angularjs, I want the validation of input required field, I created it as a directive and included inside the form in html page. my template page for directive is

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="lastName">{{::"SYSTEM_USERS.LAST_NAME_LABEL" | translate}}</label>
  <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" ng-model="systemUserInfo.lastName" ng-class="{'error': errorMessages.lastName.$error.required}" required/>
  <div ng-messages="errorMessages.lastName.$invalid" class="errors" ng-show="errorMessages.lastName.$invalid" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required" class="field-error">
      Required Field
    </div>
</div>
```

and I included this directive inside form controller is as a

```
<system-user-form user="e" show-errors="showSystemUserErrors" id="{{$index}}"></system-user-form>
```

and when i clicked on following button i want error messages in the above html page.

```
<button type="submit" class="secondary-big-button" ng-click="validtest()" ng-disabled="!editSystemUserForm.$dirty">SAVE</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or jsfiddle with this code please ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the error messages in the form, it should have a name. And you should pass the form name to the directive as well. Refer the snippet below.

```
<form name="errorMessages">
     <system-user-form form-name="errorMessages" user="e" show-errors="showSystemUserErrors" id="{{$index}}"></system-user-form>
</form>
```

In the directive, you should use the form name you passed down.

```
<div class="field">
   <label for="lastName">{{::"SYSTEM_USERS.LAST_NAME_LABEL" | translate}}</label>
   <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" ng-model="systemUserInfo.lastName" ng-class="{'error': formName.lastName.$error.required}" required/>
   <div ng-messages="formName.lastName.$invalid" class="errors" ng-show="formName.lastName.$invalid" role="alert">
       <div ng-message="required" class="field-error">
           Required Field
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And don't forget to add formName to the directive's scope. For more information refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869023/angular-js-ng-message-inside-directive).